# Android: Splash Screen API showing empty

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to impelement a splash screen.

I have followed the splash screen api approach implemented the
`implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha01"`

then used the following style

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_search</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AppTheme</item>
    </style>
```

then set the theme in the mainActivity in the manifest.xml

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
</activity>
```

and used the method intallSpalshScreen in the onCreated func

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        installSplashScreen()

        toolbar = binding.viewToolbar.tbToolbar
```

compileSDKVersion in **31**

[image: screenshot]

But the splash screen just shows a blank screen

Is there something i missed or any other way around this please let me know.

Comment: can someone please edit the size of the image. I dont know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to change the parent of the `splashTheme` from

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

to

```
 parent="Theme.SplashScreen"
```